# Generalised Linear Mixed Effect Models using latent class probabilites as weights

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model, finite-mixture-model

I'm relatively new to the field of generalised linear mixed models (GLMM) so this may be a redundant question but anyway...

I'm trying to create a regression model to predict a binary outcome where I suspect there are latent classes in the data. Using mixed effect regression I want to build a model that account for the different relationships each class has with the outcome variable. I'd like to use mixed-effect models to allow shrinkage (aka partial pooling/regularization/borrowing strength) as I expect the classes to be unbalanced.

However, as I understand it GLMM's do not account for uncertainty in class labels, unlike mixture models which use class probability as a weight to control how much effect each instance has on the model. However, mixture models do not by default allow for shrinkage. My question is, is it possible for GLMMs to account for this uncertainty and if so what is a an example of a package that implements this.

I've spotted FLXMRlmer in flexmix (an R package) which suggests that it is possible, but this model only appears to work for a linear model not a logistic model. It may also be possible using GLLAMM in Stata or PLmixed in R or through the weight arguments in various GLMMs in R but I'm not confident enough with the methods that I can be sure.

I'm using R for my analysis so I'd be even more grateful if any proposed solutions where able to point to me an appropriate package.